# See if object contains a value

Tags: java

I have a class structure in Java where one class extends another, and the subclass can have more variables than the super class does. In a function I created, I accept the super class as a parameter, and so I don't know if the object I am passing in is an instance of the subclass (and I cannot test to see if it is for a few reasons). I still want to access those variables in the subclass though, so is there anyway to search for variables in an object? I know the exact name of the variable, I just don't know if the object I will be passing in actually contains the variable, if that makes any sense.

```
@Override
public void received(Connection connection, Object object)
{
 if (object instanceof Packet)
    {
        if(packet.contains(variable))
        {
            //don't know how to test for this
        }
}
}
```

Packet is the superclass, I have another class called PacketMessage which extends Packet. I have variables in PacketMessage that aren't present in Packet.

I cannot test for PacketMessage because I'm trying to create a flexible API. I want the end user to be able to add in different classes that extend Packet, but don't necessarily have the same variables as other packets. I need to be able to test all the packet types, so I can't hard code the function to only check for one packet type.

Comment: Can you illustrate the problem with some code?

Comment: Sure, give me a second.

Comment: Is `Packet` the class that "contains" the variable? Or `Packet` is the superclass?

Comment: Packet is the superclass, I have another class called PacketMessage which extends Packet. Sorry for not explaining that!

Comment: Why don't just `object instanceof PacketMessage`?

Comment: I cannot do that because I'm trying to create a flexible API. I want the end user to be able to add in different classes that extend Packet, but don't necessarily have the same variables as other packets. I need to be able to test all the packet types, so I can't hard code it.

Comment: Then you need to add some sort of `Processor` interface that can accept objects that it understands and ignore unknown ones to it. You do not want to add that code in this method. You want to allow something else to inject it so that the new packets can be understood by injecting another processor.

Comment: @pickypg Thank you, I just thought of that myself. Don't know why I didn't earlier. I was just wondering if there was an easier way!

Comment: @opiop65 Not a way that scales.

Comment: Shouldn't the subclass be named `MessagePacket` if it's a subclass of `Packet`? The fact it isn't suggests you may have problems with your class design.

Comment: Erm no, I don't think it has to be. That's not my naming convention, and I don't see why I have "class design" issues because I didn't name it how you want me to. @Bohemian

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I need to just add an extra layer of code on top of the existing one. Each subclass of Packet that requires a specific variable must also extend another class that holds that variable. Simple logic problem, really.

Answer (score 0):

Create an interface that has the method you need:

```
interface HasSomeValue {
    public int getSomeValue();
}
```

Then have the classes that have this value implement the interface and test for that, not the supercass:

```
class PacketMessage extends Packet implements HasSomeValue {
    public int getSomeValue() {
        return 0; // whatever
    }
    // rest of class
}
```

then in your processor:

```
if (object instanceof HasSomeValue )
{
    if(((HasSomeValue) packet).getSomeValue() == ?)
    {

    }
}
```